# Read/Write Strings and Images in a single file

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binary, file-read

I'm trying to save into a single file `String + Image + String + Image ...` and then read it in the same order. The images are **PNG**! I managed to save the file so I'm more concerned about the reading part. Am I supposed to use a combination of `BinaryRead/Writers` and `PngBitmapDecoders`?

Although I am working on and WPF applicaton I found that most convenient for me is to use the WinForms'es `Image.Save()` method like so:

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(fs, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

After this line I tested to `BinaryWrite` a simple text and another image, and my Hex Reader says everything's O.K.

[image]

Now I need to figure out a way to read it. I tried `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream()` and `PngBitmapDecoder()` but they fail..

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using the [`Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class & file format to store your data.  "Package is an abstract class that can be used to organize objects into a single entity of a defined physical format for portability and efficient access.".

Comment: Barring use of an abstraction like `Package`, you still need to store enough information in the file so that your code knows where the different pieces start and stop. For example, precede each string and each PNG with a byte count, and then read the byte count followed by that number of bytes, interpreting the bytes as appropriate. For more detailed hope, write an actual implementation of something and then if it doesn't work, post a question about what you're specifically having trouble with.